# Draw random patterns using swing

Tags: java, swing, canvas, draw

I was trying to practise a bit with mouseListener events on java awt/swing and I thought to try to draw the area that my mouse passes. Something like the brush tool in windows paint. So I created a frame added a canvas and started experiment with the MouseListener's methods. But no matter what I do I cannot move past drawing a single point on click and then nothing. Can someone help me...

**EDIT**:
I have read the link below (very good tutorial) and I think that I got it. But when I tried to implement it the arraylist of points seem to be null. What am I missing because I cannot see something wrong...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;



public class Canvas extends JComponent implements MouseInputListener{

    private ArrayList<Point> coloredPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

    private Point Startpnt = null;
    private Point Endpnt = null;

    private int xMin;
    private int xMax;
    private int yMin;
    private int yMax;

    public Canvas() {
        super();
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight());

        for (int i=0; i<coloredPoints.size(); i++)
        {
            int pX = coloredPoints.get(i).getX();
            int pY = coloredPoints.get(i).getY(); 
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawRect(pX, pY, 1, 1);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Startpnt.setX(getX());
        Startpnt.setY(getY());
        Endpnt = Startpnt;
        coloredPoints.add(Endpnt);

        xMin = Startpnt.getX();
        xMax = Startpnt.getX();
        yMin = Startpnt.getY();
        yMax = Startpnt.getY(); 

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //  Repaint only the area affected by the mouse dragging
        Endpnt.setX(e.getX());
        Endpnt.setY(e.getY());
        xMin = Math.min(xMin, Endpnt.getX());
        xMax = Math.max(xMax, Endpnt.getX());
        yMin = Math.min(yMin, Endpnt.getY());
        yMax = Math.max(yMax, Endpnt.getY());
        repaint(xMin, yMin, 1, 1);
        coloredPoints.add(Endpnt);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        Startpnt = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    class Point {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

    }


}
```

This is the code I wrote for the canvas class. I want to have a black background and draw red patterns...
I use eclipse so some things are auto-generated...

Comment: Why dont you add some code to show what you have done?

Comment: If you were to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you have, you would get better help sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But no matter what I do I cannot move past drawing a single point on click and then nothing.

Well it sounds like you are just repainting the last point. You need to keep track of all points to be painted.

You can start by taking a look at [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways do this. This example paints Rectangles, but you should be able to modify it to paint dots.

Edit:

> But when I tried to implement it the arraylist of points seem to be null.

Well is it or isn't it? It is very easy to tell. Just add a System.out.println(..) in the painting code to see how many entries you have.

Other comments:

1. Why are you overriding paint()? The code given to you overrides paintComponent() which is the proper way to do custom painting.
2. Why do you have variables "Endppnt". The code given to you uses "endPoint". Again Java variable naming standards are to use a lower case to start the variable name. Don't make up your own conventions.
3. Don't call your component "Canvas". There is an AWT class by that name so it is confusing. The class name should be more descriptive.
4. You don't need to create your own Point class. The JDK already has a Point class that does what you want.
5. You don't really need the startPnt/endPnt logic since you are adding a single pixel to the ArrayList every time you drag the mouse. The example code needed to keep track of the start/end so it could determine the bounds of the Rectangle.

If you need more help then post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). We can't tell how the panel is added to the frame and we can't execute your code.